# Rails Saving User Selected Foreign Key In Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie to Rails and I have been struggling with this idea that just can't get over my head. For example I have

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :survey
end
```

I have created a set of surveys. Now I want to create some questions and assign it to the survey through its foreign key survey_id. In the Question new.html.erb page, I used advanced form to show the Survey ID(I followed [this tutorial](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/advanced-forms)). It works fine however, when I click submit, it seems like the survey_id doesn't save.

This is my question_controller.rb

```
def create
@question = Question.create(question_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @question.save
    format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
  end
end

def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(:description, :date_created, :survey_id)
end
```

Here is the form:

```
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :survey_id %><br>
       <%= collection_select(:question, :survey_id, Survey.all, :id, :description, prompt: true ) %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I know in order for this to work, I have to do something like

```
@question = @survey.questions.create(...)
```

but I have no idea how to get the @survey instance before the user click on the drop down and select the appropriate survey.

Anyone has any idea on how to do this ??

Comment: show your `question_params`

Comment: added question_params

Comment: can you show params that you receiver in your controller, what you see in console for params?

Comment: can you show the `form` view that you're using?

Comment: added form that I am using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your create method should be

```
def create
 @survey = Survey.find(params[:survey_id])
 @question = @survey.questions.create(question_params)

 respond_to do |format|
  if @question.save
   format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' }
  else
   format.html { render :new }
 end
end
```

or you can also use filter

```
  class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :set_survey, only: :create

     def create
      @question = @survey.questions.create(question_params)

     respond_to do |format|
       if @question.save
         format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' }
       else
        format.html { render :new }
       end
      end

      private
        def set_survey
           @survey = Survey.find(params[:survey_id]) || Survey.new
        end  

    end
```

Answer (score 2):

you have survey objects created and you want them to be associated to questions,

so, on your question's form if you are using select drop-down with survey names to select from then set **select options values to survey id**. so your `question params` will contain `survey_id` parameter with value equal to selected survey's id. and thus `Question.create(question_params)` will create question with survey_id.

Comment: Hi @Anuja, I have uploaded the form. It seems right but the survey_id doesn't get save :(

Comment: yes, everything seems right. what is your request response? are you getting any error? plz add your server log.

Comment: if your `survey_id` param is not passed as nested hash within question then, approach suggested by Rajarshi will work for you. or In controller you can do like this `@question = Question.create(question_params)` and `@question.survey_id = params[:survey_id]`